# Sort by long numbers, longer than Long data type

Tags: sorting, elasticsearch, opensearch

I have got numbers such as the following

- 14943946763064166065064222914309811179884629895193213215294437936375446976774

I want to sort by numbers of the same length, I have tried Long and Keyword mapping types but nothing worked.

Comment: What do these numbers represent?

Comment: @ilvar, they represent IDs. This may sound stupid but I used Double data type and it worked, thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone that end up here, I used Double data type and it worked well